AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller not recognized after messing with the configuration
I have messed up my kernel somehow (probably during tries with igpu pass through, but it's just a guess), and now it won't recognize the "AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller" on latest kernel (6.8.0-31-generic). With the same /etc/modprobe.d/ config the Audio Controller is properly loaded by an older 6.8.0-28 kernel.
This is the snd_hda_intel related modules list on both kernels:
6.8.0-28-generic modules:
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         217088  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core          151552  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_pcm               200704  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd                   147456  26 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_ump,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi

6.8.0-31-generic modules:
snd_hda_intel          61440  1
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         217088  2 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core          151552  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               200704  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd                   147456  20 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_ump,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi

As You can see, some modules are missing on 6.8.31, but even if i load them manually, the device won't show up, even after pipewire restart. I checked live USB which comes with 6.8.31, and the device is recognize there. I have searched dmesg, but couldn't find anything related. What else could i do to get the sound back with the latest 6.8.31 kernel?
Below lspci output for the problematic device:
lspci -nnkvs 19:00.6
19:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller [1849:6899]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at fca80000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel


I can't really tell what helped. i did few things:

get /etc/modprobe.d/ from fresh install and replace with it my messed modprobe.d folder,
remove all custom files from /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/*
finally do update-initramfs -u -k 6.8.0-31-generic

I guess that the main reason for the problem was the file /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/vfio-pci-override-vga.sh, created by passthrough_helper_ubuntu_20 script. I will mess around some more to confirm this thesis. Anyway the problem with missing AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio device is resolved so far.
